# How to get rid of "The documentation for this class was generated from the following files" paragraph?

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen

What option, and where it is in the GUI front end, do I need to set to remove the paragraph

> The documentation for this class was generated from the following files:

from my project documentation pages?

Alternatively, how do I get rid of the absolute paths in this list of files, for example `C:/Users/Avesta/Desktop/CF/trunnk/CloudServer/` in the snippet below:

[image]?

Comment: Pls,describe the problem

Comment: I would like to not see that paragraph. And wonder how to make Doxygen not to generate it.

Comment: In the Expert wizard,select Input and manually browse the absolute  path.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The visibility of the section that shows which files have been used is controlled by the `SHOW_USED_FILES` setting.

Doxygen will show absolute paths when `FULL_PATH_NAMES` is set to `YES` and the relevant part is not stripped off via `STRIP_FROM_PATH`.

So either setting

```
SHOW_USED_FILES = NO
```

or setting

```
FULL_PATH_NAMES = NO
```

or setting

```
FULL_PATH_NAMES = YES
STRIP_FROM_PATH = C:/Users/Avesta/Desktop/CF/trunk/CloudServer
```

should solve your problem.